# Преобразование типов в операторе if (javascript)

Tags: javascript

> hits1 - это массив, его длина равна числу положенных в него элементов. `hits1.push(i)` кладет в него число i, если найдено совпадение в text со строкой myName. Проверка `if (hits1.length)` расшифровывается как `if ((bool)hits1.length)`, при этом (bool) возвращает ложь, если ему передали пустоту или 0, и истину в остальных случаях. Соответственно, если эта длина оказывается нулем (т.е. совпадений не найдено), список совпадений не пытается выводиться, если не ноль, выполняется цикл по массиву.

А почему это не срабатывает когда пишешь `if(hits.length === 0)`

Comment: Все срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще в вашем случае все срабатывает. Однако могу предположить следующее.
Если вы пишите что-то вроде:

```
var fff = 0;
if(fff.length === 0)
{
  console.log("ok");
}
else
{
  console.log(fff.length);
}
```

То вывод будет `udefined`. Это происходит от того, что `fff` не массив вызов `fff.length` возвращает `undefined`, а не 0.
Если написать `var fff = [];` то все будет корректно работать.
Также стоит знать, что проверка на идентичность `===` не преобразует типы вообще. Истина тут будет если только справа и слева будут одинаковые значения (например `undefined === undefined` ). Для преобразования типов используйте равенство `==` (например `'' == 0` или `undefined == null`)